# Cannot pre-load keyfile (ta.key)

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn

I tried this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-22-04) on my VB and when i run `sudo systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service`  I got the following error instead

```
 openvpn-server@server.service - OpenVPN service for server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-04-27 17:52:13 UTC; 2s ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 14624 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn-server/status-server.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --c>
   Main PID: 14624 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"
        CPU: 54ms
```

I also tried `/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn/server.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/server.pid`  to view errors and got

```
2023-04-27 17:52:25 WARNING: --topology net30 support for server configs with IPv4 pools will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to --topology subnet as soon as possible.
2023-04-27 17:52:25 Cannot pre-load keyfile (ta.key)
2023-04-27 17:52:25 Exiting due to fatal error
```

What does this error mean and how to solve it?